# Reinstall Server OS - Save files and programs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

WE have been experiencing many issues with our server, when it would initially lose connection with the Printer. This escalated to the Printer Properties hanging, then the Devices and Printers, and now the Control Panel hangs whenever we try to access Devices and Printers (all other functions work fine).

Additionally, other PCs on the network are having issues communicating with the Server in this state, requiring a refresh of the program in order to boot and respond correctly. No other solutions have been able to resolve the issues, so it's getting to the stage where a OS reinstall is required.

However, I don't want to wipe the hard drive, since there are many other files on there that are needed, so I just want to re-install the OS. Can I wipe (delete) the partition(s) that has the OS installed, without affecting the rest of the PC, and if so, which one(s)?

Comment: If your important files are not on the system partition, simply installing Windows Server on that partition wouldn't touch your other partitions, you should of course already have a backup of those files.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can just reinstall the server OS with the system partition, and if you have important files and programs in the system partition, you can move them to other partitions. And re-install the server OS will not affect the other partitions.

Or, you can backup your important files and apps by some software before you reinstall the server OS, if you are still worry about it.
Like this:[Handy Backup](https://www.handybackup.net/application-backup.shtml)